# Make API call on page load (Django)

Tags: django

I'm building a basic Django site.
Currently, I'm trying figure out a way to make an API call and retrieve the results on page load.
Is it possible to use the js .onload function to call a Django view function?

Any suggestions/tips would be appreciated!

Comment: call backend API URL on js onload function. get data from your api view . play with response data in js.

Answer (score 1):

you can use "requests" library and making a request on the django view for this page.

```
import requests

def my_view(request):
    r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
    context = {
         'data': r.json()
    }
    return render(request, 'my_html.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use JavaScript fetch API like following:

***page.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="msg"></h1>
<script>
  var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/message';
  fetch(url).then(
    response => response.json()
  ).then(function(data) {
    document.getElementById("msg").textContent = data['message'];
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

***views.html***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse


def index(request):
    return render(request, "index.html")


def message(request):    
    return JsonResponse({"message": "Hello World!"})
```